# How to tell at runtime if my process is CPU bound or I/O bound

Tags: c#, networking, .net-4.0, io, compression

I have a program where I send data over TCP link. I am using Asynchronous Reads and writes to both the disk and network. If I put a [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yy62ycx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the middle (so I compress before I write to the network link and I decompress when I receive the data and write it out to the disk) I am CPU bound on the compressing side. This causes my max transfer rate to be about `300 KB/s`. However if I remove the compression step I am now I/O bound to the disk and I get transfer rates of `40,000 KB/s`.

Under strictly LAN conditions my upper I/O limit will always be more than 300 KB/s, however if my program is run over the internet I very well may have a network IO limit below 300 KB/s.

I would like to detect if I am I/O bound and my network/disk link is the limiting factor or if I am CPU bound and the act of compressing is what is slowing me down most. How could I detect if my program is being limited by my CPU or by my I/O at runtime so I could switch protocols and get the best possible transfer rate?

```
private static void SendFile(string filename, NetworkStream stream, int sendBufferSize)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan))
    using (var ds = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        StreamUtilities.CopyAsync(fs, ds, sendBufferSize);
    }
}

public static void CopyAsync(Stream sourceStream, Stream destStream, int bufferSize = 4096)
{
    Byte[] bufferA = new Byte[bufferSize];
    Byte[] bufferB = new Byte[bufferSize];

    IAsyncResult writeResult = null;
    IAsyncResult readResult = null;

    bool readBufferA = false;
    int read;

    readResult = sourceStream.BeginRead(bufferA, 0, bufferA.Length, null, null);
    //Complete last read
    while ((read = sourceStream.EndRead(readResult)) > 0)
    {
        if (readBufferA)
        {
            PerformOperations(sourceStream, destStream, bufferA, bufferB, ref readResult, ref writeResult, read);
        }
        else
        {
            PerformOperations(sourceStream, destStream, bufferB, bufferA, ref readResult, ref writeResult, read);
        }

        //Flip the bit on the next buffer
        readBufferA = !readBufferA;
    }
    if (writeResult != null)
        destStream.EndWrite(writeResult);
}

private static void PerformOperations(Stream sourceStream, Stream destStream, Byte[] readBuffer, Byte[] writeBuffer, ref IAsyncResult readResult, ref IAsyncResult writeResult, int bytesToWrite)
{
    //Start next read
    readResult = sourceStream.BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, null, null);

    //End previous write
    if (writeResult != null)
        destStream.EndWrite(writeResult);
    writeResult = destStream.BeginWrite(writeBuffer, 0, bytesToWrite, null, null);
}
```

Comment: But of course the compression process is what's slowing you down... Try putting that on another thread.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I am using Asyncronous I/O, the read and write are already on seperate threads (ok, it's not really threads, it's the Aysnc IO system in the kernal, but it has the same affect)

Comment: Yeah, but is the compression on the same thread as the write IO? Each compression should have it's own thread (well, sort of), and whenever there's an "Whop, I'm done!" by a compressor thread, an async write operation takes place.

Comment: I beleive it is on the same thread as the read IO, I think [Jon's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13573413/80274) is my solution but I don't want to accept an answer too quickly to discourage other answers.

Comment: In the old days you just watched the tape drives to see if they stopped moving. Ah me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to separate the two aspects out into a producer/consumer queue: your compressor write blocks into a queue which is then consumed by a thread which just performs IO.

That way:

- You can compress while the IO is occurring, without going into asynchronous IO
- You can detect whether you're CPU bound (queue is normally empty, or briefly has 1 block on it) or IO bound (queue gradually gets bigger as you compress faster than it can be sent)
- With a bit of work, you could multi-thread the compression; you'd need to keep track of block order, but that should be feasible.